# Most secure solution to upload to S3 via mobile app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to upload files on AWS S3 via a mobile app. I found 2 solutions to deal with it.
Both solutions work, but I am not competent enough to determine what is the most secure one.

1. Using **temporary credentials** provided by Secure Token Service (STS) Amazon Web Services.

   1. My server asks for temporary credentials (with restricted rights) to STS using the AWS account access_key_id & secret_access_key
   2. My server then send the temporary credentials (access_key_id, secret_access_key & session_token) to the mobile app
   3. The mobile app send the file on S3 using the temporary credentials with a specific request signature (computed on the mobile side)
2. Using **permanent credentials** (AWS account access_key_id & secret_access_key)

   1. My server directly create a request signature (using the AWS account access_key_id & secret_access_key) and send the request "elements/structure" (included the generated signature, the needed headers,...) to the mobile app
   2. The mobile app send the file on S3 using the "elements" with the signature provided by the server

The second solution is simpler. But that solution seems to be less secure:
the account access_key_id is exposed and the signature directly generated with the account secret_access_key.
The digest algorithm used to generate the signature is HMAC-SHA1. Is it secure enough ?

The second solution expose temporary credentials with expiration: it is much more secure to expose limited credentials. If the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm is secure enough to make the secret_access_key impossible to retrieve, I do not see why I would chose this solution.

Thank you for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Your temporary solution is essentially a [Token Vending Machine](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490). This is our recommended method for getting credentials onto the device for use with our AWS Mobile SDKs.  The inherent benefit of shipping temporary credentials is that they could be used to access other services besides S3.